# First message is duplicated

Tags: android, android-studio, quickblox

I've been working on a messaging app and within the group and private chat, the first message duplicates and then when another message is sent, it's hidden behind the duplicated text until another one is sent and then so on. Can anybody help me with this problem? I'm using Quickblox as a database

**ChatMessage Class**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Adapter.ChatMessageAdapter;
import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Common.Common;
import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Holder.QBChatMessagesHolder;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBIncomingMessagesManager;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBRestChatService;
import com.quickblox.chat.exception.QBChatException;
import com.quickblox.chat.listeners.QBChatDialogMessageListener;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatMessage;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialogType;
import com.quickblox.chat.request.QBDialogRequestBuilder;
import com.quickblox.chat.request.QBMessageGetBuilder;
import com.quickblox.chat.request.QBMessageUpdateBuilder;
import com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback;
import com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException;
import org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.DiscussionHistory;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ChatMessage extends AppCompatActivity  implements 
QBChatDialogMessageListener{

QBChatDialog qbChatDialog;
ListView lstChatMessages;
ImageButton submitButton;
EditText edtContent;

ChatMessageAdapter adapter;


int contextMenuIndexClicked = -1;
boolean isEditMode = false;
QBChatMessage editMessage;



Toolbar toolbar;


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.chat_group_edit_name:
            editNameGroup();
            break;
        case R.id.chat_group_add_user:
            addUser();
            break;
        case R.id.chat_group_remove_user:
            removeUser();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void removeUser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ListUsers.class);
    intent.putExtra(Common.UPDATE_DIALOG_EXTRA, qbChatDialog);
    intent.putExtra(Common.UPDATE_MODE, Common.UPDATE_REMOVE_MODE);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void addUser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ListUsers.class);
    intent.putExtra(Common.UPDATE_DIALOG_EXTRA, qbChatDialog);
    intent.putExtra(Common.UPDATE_MODE,Common.UPDATE_ADD_MODE);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void editNameGroup() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_edit_group_layout, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
    final EditText newName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edt_group_name);

    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    qbChatDialog.setName(newName.getText().toString());

                    QBDialogRequestBuilder requestBuilder = new QBDialogRequestBuilder();
                    QBRestChatService.updateGroupChatDialog(qbChatDialog, requestBuilder)
                            .performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBChatDialog>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(QBChatDialog qbChatDialog, Bundle bundle) {
                                    Toast.makeText(ChatMessage.this, "Group name edited", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    toolbar.setTitle(qbChatDialog.getName());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    if (qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP || qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP)
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_message_group_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    contextMenuIndexClicked = info.position;

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.chat_message_update:
            updateMessage();
            break;
        case R.id.chat_message_delete:
            deleteMessage();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void deleteMessage() {
    final ProgressDialog deleteDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatMessage.this);
    deleteDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    deleteDialog.show();

    editMessage = QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().getChatMessagesByDialogId(qbChatDialog.getDialogId())
            .get(contextMenuIndexClicked);

    QBRestChatService.deleteMessage(editMessage.getId(),false).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
            retrieveAllMessage();
            deleteDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

        }
    });
}

private void updateMessage() {
    editMessage = QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().getChatMessagesByDialogId(qbChatDialog.getDialogId())
            .get(contextMenuIndexClicked);
    edtContent.setText(editMessage.getBody());
    isEditMode = true;
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.chat_message_content_menu, menu);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    qbChatDialog.removeMessageListrener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    qbChatDialog.removeMessageListrener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_message);



    initViews();

    initChatDialogs();

    retrieveAllMessage();


    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!edtContent.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
            if (!isEditMode) {
                QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
                chatMessage.setBody(edtContent.getText().toString());
                chatMessage.setSenderId(QBChatService.getInstance().getUser().getId());
                chatMessage.setSaveToHistory(true);

                try {
                    qbChatDialog.sendMessage(chatMessage);
                } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                if (qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PRIVATE){

                    QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().putMessage(qbChatDialog.getDialogId(),chatMessage);
                    ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages = QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().getChatMessagesByDialogId(chatMessage.getDialogId());
                    adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getBaseContext(),messages);
                    lstChatMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }


                edtContent.setText("");
                edtContent.setFocusable(true);

            }else
            {
                final ProgressDialog updateDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatMessage.this);
                updateDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                updateDialog.show();

                QBMessageUpdateBuilder messageUpdateBuilder = new QBMessageUpdateBuilder();
                messageUpdateBuilder.updateText(edtContent.getText().toString()).markDelivered().markRead();

                QBRestChatService.updateMessage(editMessage.getId(),qbChatDialog.getDialogId(),messageUpdateBuilder)
                        .performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid, Bundle bundle) {
                                retrieveAllMessage();
                                isEditMode = false;
                                updateDialog.dismiss();

                                edtContent.setText("");
                                edtContent.setFocusable(true);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
            }
        }
    });

}

private void retrieveAllMessage() {
    QBMessageGetBuilder messageGetBuilder = new QBMessageGetBuilder();
    messageGetBuilder.setLimit(500);

    if(qbChatDialog != null){
        QBRestChatService.getDialogMessages(qbChatDialog,messageGetBuilder).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBChatMessage>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBChatMessage> qbChatMessages, Bundle bundle) {

                QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().putMessages(qbChatDialog.getDialogId(),qbChatMessages);

                adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getBaseContext(),qbChatMessages);
                lstChatMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {

            }
        });
    }
}

private void initChatDialogs() {
    qbChatDialog = (QBChatDialog)getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Common.DIALOG_EXTRA);
    qbChatDialog.initForChat(QBChatService.getInstance());

    QBIncomingMessagesManager incomingMessage = QBChatService.getInstance().getIncomingMessagesManager();
    incomingMessage.addDialogMessageListener(new QBChatDialogMessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(String s, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage, Integer integer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void processError(String s, QBChatException e, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage, Integer integer) {

        }
    });

    if (qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.PUBLIC_GROUP || qbChatDialog.getType() == QBDialogType.GROUP){
        DiscussionHistory discussionHistory = new DiscussionHistory();
        discussionHistory.setMaxStanzas(0);

        qbChatDialog.join(discussionHistory, new QBEntityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.d("ERROR", ""+e.getMessage());

            }
        });


    }
    qbChatDialog.addMessageListener(this);

    toolbar.setTitle(qbChatDialog.getName());
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

private void initViews() {

    lstChatMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.messages_list);
    submitButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.send);
    edtContent = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_content);





    registerForContextMenu(lstChatMessages);

    toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.chatmessage_toolbar);

}



@Override
public void processMessage(String s, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage, Integer integer) {
    QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().putMessage(qbChatMessage.getDialogId(),qbChatMessage);
    ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages = QBChatMessagesHolder.getInstance().getChatMessagesByDialogId(qbChatMessage.getDialogId());
    adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(getBaseContext(),messages);
    lstChatMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void processError(String s, QBChatException e, QBChatMessage qbChatMessage, Integer integer) {
    Log.e("ERROR",""+e.getMessage());
}
}
```

ChatMessageAdapter Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.github.library.bubbleview.BubbleTextView;
import com.liftersheaven.messaging.Holder.QBUsersHolder;
import com.liftersheaven.messaging.R;
import com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService;
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatMessage;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class ChatMessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context context;
private ArrayList<QBChatMessage> qbChatMessages;

public ChatMessageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QBChatMessage> qbChatMessages){
    this.context = context;
    this.qbChatMessages = qbChatMessages;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return qbChatMessages.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return qbChatMessages.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (qbChatMessages.get(position).getSenderId().equals(QBChatService.getInstance().getUser().getId())){
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_message_send, null);
            BubbleTextView bubbleTextView = (BubbleTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_content);
            bubbleTextView.setText(qbChatMessages.get(position).getBody());
        }
        else{
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_recieve_message, null);
            BubbleTextView bubbleTextView = (BubbleTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_recieve);
            bubbleTextView.setText(qbChatMessages.get(position).getBody());
            TextView txtName = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            txtName.setText(QBUsersHolder.getInstance().getUserById(qbChatMessages.get(position).getSenderId()).getFullName());
        }
    }
    return view;
}
}
```

QBChatMessagesHolder Class

```
import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatMessage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class QBChatMessagesHolder {
private static   QBChatMessagesHolder instance;
private HashMap<String,ArrayList<QBChatMessage>> qbChatMessageArray;

public static synchronized QBChatMessagesHolder getInstance(){
    QBChatMessagesHolder qbChatMessagesHolder;
    synchronized (QBChatMessagesHolder.class){
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new QBChatMessagesHolder();
        qbChatMessagesHolder = instance;
    }
    return qbChatMessagesHolder;
}

private QBChatMessagesHolder(){
    this.qbChatMessageArray = new HashMap<>();
}

public void putMessages(String dialogId,ArrayList<QBChatMessage> qbChatMessages){
    this.qbChatMessageArray.put(dialogId,qbChatMessages);
}

public void putMessage(String dialogId,QBChatMessage qbChatMessage){
    List<QBChatMessage> lstResult = (List)this.qbChatMessageArray.get(dialogId);
    lstResult.add(qbChatMessage);
    ArrayList<QBChatMessage> lstAdded = new ArrayList(lstResult.size());
    lstAdded.addAll(lstResult);
    putMessages(dialogId, lstAdded);
}

public ArrayList<QBChatMessage> getChatMessagesByDialogId(String dialogId){
    return (ArrayList<QBChatMessage>)this.qbChatMessageArray.get(dialogId);
}
}
```